# Django: generic.UpdateView with form_class won't render form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm having a really confusing issue with some views in Django.  I created Update and Create views, both using the generic versions, both using the same template.  They worked perfectly...until I added a custom modelForm to exclude a field.  Now, the Create view still works correctly, but the Update view won't render a form at all.

Form:

```
class member_form(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model=member
          exclude=('created_by',)
```

Views:

```
class member_detail(generic.UpdateView):
     form_class=member_form
     model=member
     template_name_suffix='_detail'

class member_create(generic.CreateView):
     form_class=member_form
     model=member
     template_name_suffix='_detail'
```

Urls (main):

```
url(r'^members/',include(members.urls',namespace=members),name='members_list'),
```

Urls (app):

```
url(r'^$',login_required(views.member_list.as_view()),name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',login_required(views.member_detail.as_view(success_url=".")),name='detail'),
url(r'^new/$',permission_required('members.add_member')(views.member_create.as_view(success_url='/members/')),name='create'),
```

This worked perfectly for both views until I added the form_class.  Now, member_create still works perfectly, but member_detail shows nothing for {{ form.as_table }}.  When I switch it to just {{ form }} in that template, I get this for member_detail:

```
<members.views.member_form object at 0x7f7de3f20d50>
```

What's going on here?  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code. Could you post your `urls.py`?

Comment: Added the relevant lines from urls.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a stupid naming mistake on my part, on the production code, which I found while trying to redact new sections to add to the question; the _create and _form objects in my question were both named _form in production.